# problema al pasar $_SESSION

Tags: php, html, web, session

**Login.html**

```
</div>
<div class="col">
  <form action="../php/comprobar_inicio_sesion.php" method="POST" name="form_login">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="campo_email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Introduce tu email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Nunca mostraremos tu <b>email</b> a nadie.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Contraseña</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="campo_contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Nunca mostraremos tu <b>contraseña</b> a nadie.</small>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a  id="boton_menu" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="comprobarCampos()">Inicia Sesion !!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <a  id="btn_atras" href="../index.html" class="btn btn-info align-middle">atras</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> Tengo aqui mi inicio de sesion con un form. Que pasara los datos de los inputs text al siguiente  fichero php que comprobar su existencia.

**ComprobarInicioSesion.php**

> ```
> > comprueba que el usuario existe para abrir el inicio logeado de la pagina
> ```

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!--  CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css">

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

<?php
      include 'conexion.php';

      $tabla="noesrarosepresta_usuarios";
    /*
      $nombre = "pepito";
      $apel_1 = "perez";
      $apel_2 = "rodriguez";
      $email = "pepito@gmail.com";
      $contraseña = "atiketesale";
      */
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $password =  $_POST['password'];


    /*  $query = "SELECT 'usuario_email', 'usuario_password' FROM `$tabla`
       WHERE usuario_email= `$email` AND
        usuario_password=`$password`";*/

        $query= "SELECT *
        FROM `$tabla`
        WHERE usuario_email = '$email' AND
        usuario_password = '$password'";


      $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
//si existe al menos uno ( que solo va a salir uno si es que existe)
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {




              $_SESSION["id"]=  $row['usuario_id'] ;
              $_SESSION["nombre"]=  $row['usuario_nombre'] ;
              $_SESSION["user"] = $row['usuario_user'];
              $_SESSION["apel_1"]=  $row['usuario_apel_1'] ;
              $_SESSION["apel_2"]=  $row['usuario_apel_2'] ;
              $_SESSION["email"]=  $row['usuario_email'] ;
              $_SESSION["password"]=  $row['usuario_password'] ;
              $_SESSION["mensajes"]=  $row['usuario_mensajes'] ;


            if (headers_sent()) {

                 header("Location:../html/inicio.php");

                   $_SESSION["id"]=  $row['usuario_id'] ;
              $_SESSION["nombre"]=  $row['usuario_nombre'] ;
              $_SESSION["user"] = $row['usuario_user'];
              $_SESSION["apel_1"]=  $row['usuario_apel_1'] ;
              $_SESSION["apel_2"]=  $row['usuario_apel_2'] ;
              $_SESSION["email"]=  $row['usuario_email'] ;
              $_SESSION["password"]=  $row['usuario_password'] ;
              $_SESSION["mensajes"]=  $row['usuario_mensajes'] ;

            }
            else {



              $_SESSION["id"]=  $row['usuario_id'] ;
              $_SESSION["nombre"]=  $row['usuario_nombre'] ;
              $_SESSION["user"] = $row['usuario_user'];
              $_SESSION["apel_1"]=  $row['usuario_apel_1'] ;
              $_SESSION["apel_2"]=  $row['usuario_apel_2'] ;
              $_SESSION["email"]=  $row['usuario_email'] ;
              $_SESSION["password"]=  $row['usuario_password'] ;
              $_SESSION["mensajes"]=  $row['usuario_mensajes'] ;


                                 header("Location:../html/inicio.php");

            }

        }

  //abro la siguiente pagina

            //header("Location:../html/inicio.php");
           // header("../html/inicio.php");
           // exit();





      }
      else {


        echo "<h1> <small>EL USUARIO NO EXISTE</small></h1>";
        header('Location: pag_error.php');
      }






?>

  </body>
</html>

<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

**BarraMenu.php**

> Barramenu.php es un componente que me he creado para hacer un `include "fichero.php"` y ahorrarme codigo en todas las paginas. El problemas es que no esta leyendo las variables que se les pasa. Entonces al ejecutar ese include me dice que no reconoce las variables

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{


    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    $id = $_SESSION["id"];
    $nombre = $_SESSION['nombre'] ;
    $apel_1 =  $_SESSION['apel_1'] ;
    $apel_2=  $_SESSION['apel_2'] ;
    $email=  $_SESSION['email'] ;
    $password=  $_SESSION['password'] ;
    $mensajes=  $_SESSION['mensajes'] ;


}
else{

    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    $id = $_SESSION["id"];
    $nombre = $_SESSION['nombre'] ;
    $apel_1 =  $_SESSION['apel_1'] ;
    $apel_2=  $_SESSION['apel_2'] ;
    $email=  $_SESSION['email'] ;
    $password=  $_SESSION['password'] ;
    $mensajes=  $_SESSION['mensajes'] ;


}

echo  $_SESSION['id'];
echo  $_SESSION['user'];
echo  $_SESSION['nombre'];
echo  $_SESSION['apel_1'];
echo  $_SESSION['apel_2'];
echo  $_SESSION['email'];
echo  $_SESSION['password'];
echo  $_SESSION['mensajes'];



?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <img id="icono_usuario" src="https://www.infojobs.net/ficha.foto?quina=62883927-06B0-F816-BA69AF6E0555C34B" alt="">
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <span class="navbar-brand" href="#"><?php
    echo "<h3 id='titulo_nombre'> <small>
      <b>$user</b>
    </small></h3>";
    ?></span>
  </div>


<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="../html/inicio.php">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="../html/crear_tarjeta.php">Crear Tarjeta</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="../html/ver_usuarios.php">Ver todos los usuarios</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>

    <li>

      <span class="navbar-brand" href="#"><?php
      echo "<h3 id='titulo_cant_mens_creados'> <small>
        <b>$mensajes tarjetas creadas</b>
        </small></h3>";
        ?></span>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <a  href="../php/cerrar_sesion.php"  class="btn btn-danger">Salir</a>
</div>
```

**Inicio.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--  CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilo_entrado.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css"> -->

    <title>Inicio</title>
  </head>


  <style >

  </style>
  <body>

    <?php


      //VARIABLES QUE RECUPERO DEL FICHERO COMPROBACION DE usuario

      if(isset($_SESSION))
      {
          session_start();
        //  $pk = $_SESSION["PK"];
          $id = $_SESSION["id"];
          $nombre = $_SESSION['nombre'] ;
          $user = $_SESSION['user'];
          $apel_1 =  $_SESSION['apel_1'] ;
          $apel_2=  $_SESSION['apel_2'] ;
          $email=  $_SESSION['email'] ;
          $password=  $_SESSION['password'] ;
          $mensajes=  $_SESSION['mensajes'] ;





      /*  $datos_user[0] =   $_SESSION["id"];
        $datos_user[1] =   $_SESSION["nombre"];
        $datos_user[2] =   $_SESSION["apel_1"];
        $datos_user[3] =   $_SESSION["apel_2"];
        $datos_user[4] =   $_SESSION["email"];
        $datos_user[5] =   $_SESSION["password"];
        $datos_user[6] =   $_SESSION["mensajes"];*/
      }


     ?>


     <?php
         // MENU
        include '../php/componentes/barra_menu.php';
      ?>




<div class="container">

  <!-- CONTENIDO -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8" id="cuerpo">
      <h1 id="titulo_apartado">Inicio</h1>
      <!-- APARTADO TARJETAS -->

      <?php include "../php/componentes/listar_tarjetas_creadas.php" ?>


      </div>
    <!--  APARTADO NOTICIAS INICIO-->
    <?php include "../php/componentes/apartado_noticias.php" ?>
    <!--
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3" id="tablon">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h3 id="titulo_tablon" class="text-center">Noticias</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div  id="sub_apartado" class="col">
          <h6><b>La tarjeta mas votada</b></h6>
          <p>Titulo: <?php echo "string"; ?></p>
          <p>Autor: </p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h6><b>Usuario con mas tarejtas creadas</b></h6>
          <p>'Nombre usuario'</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h6><b>Nuevos usuarios</b></h6>
          <ol>
            <li>Usuario nuevo </li>
            <li>Usuario nuevo </li>
            <li>Usuario nuevo </li>
            <li>Usuario nuevo </li>
            <li>Usuario nuevo </li>
          </ol>

        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
 -->
    <!--APARTADO NOTICIAS FIN  -->
  </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>


<?php
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

**SALIDA DEL ERROR**

> Notice: Undefined index: user in
>   /storage/ssd2/728/5405728/public_html/php/componentes/barra_menu.php
>   on line 35
>
> Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   /storage/ssd2/728/5405728/public_html/php/componentes/barra_menu.php
>   on line 37
>
> Notice: Undefined index: nombre in
>   /storage/ssd2/728/5405728/public_html/php/componentes/barra_menu.php
>   on line 38
>
> Notice: Undefined index: apel_1 in
>   /storage/ssd2/728/5405728/public_html/php/componentes/barra_menu.php
>   on line 39
>
> Notice: Undefined index: apel_2 in
>   /storage/ssd2/728/5405728/public_html/php/componentes/barra_menu.php
>   on line 40
>
> Notice: Undefined index: email in
>   /storage/ssd2/728/5405728/public_html/php/componentes/barra_menu.php
>   on line 41
>
> Notice: Undefined index: password in
>   /storage/ssd2/728/5405728/public_html/php/componentes/barra_menu.php
>   on line 42
>
> Notice: Undefined index: mensajes in
>   /storage/ssd2/728/5405728/public_html/php/componentes/barra_menu.php
>   on line 43
>
> Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   /storage/ssd2/728/5405728/public_html/php/componentes/barra_menu.php
>   on line 48

Comment: lo que no entiendo es que en el boton submit estas haciendo una llamada a una funcion `onclick="comprobarCampos()` y no veo que agregaste ese archivo js en tu pregunta

Comment: En ComprobarInicioSesion necesitas iniciar la sesion antes de empezar a asignar valores a la sesion. Y en el codigo inicial de BarraMenu adjudicas valores de sesion aunque no haya sesion, no tiene mucho sentido,  deberias crearla si no existe.

Comment: @andygibbs no te preocupes por eso, eso es un js que verifica los campos que si funciona , no lo puse sorry, pero gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en el archivo de `comprobar_inicio_sesion.php` no inicias session... chequea asi...

```
 $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
//si existe al menos uno ( que solo va a salir uno si es que existe)
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//inicia session;
session_start()


          $_SESSION["id"]=  $row['usuario_id'] ;
          $_SESSION["nombre"]=  $row['usuario_nombre'] ;
          $_SESSION["user"] = $row['usuario_user'];
          $_SESSION["apel_1"]=  $row['usuario_apel_1'] ;
          $_SESSION["apel_2"]=  $row['usuario_apel_2'] ;
          $_SESSION["email"]=  $row['usuario_email'] ;
          $_SESSION["password"]=  $row['usuario_password'] ;
          $_SESSION["mensajes"]=  $row['usuario_mensajes'] ;
```

buena suerte bro y ojala te ayude By; JJ

Comment: esto me lo soluciono!!,

Comment: me alegra mucho que te haya ayudado bro!!! ReNiceCode By: JJ